# How to get node subpath imports intellisense working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Recently, i started using subpath imports in my node project for mainly my utilities directory. It allowed me to go from

```js
const { promptMessage } = require('../../../../utils/promptMessage.js');
```

to

```js
const { promptMessage } = require('#utils/promptMessage.js');
```

The problem i have however, is that my intellisense is no longer working. I found some things with jsconfig.json, but those only seem to work on import statements, not require(). Is there a way to get intellisense with subpath imports?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In combination with the imports in package.json i was able to get back intellisense by creating a jsconfig.json file looking like this:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "#utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
            "#database/*": ["./database/*"],
            "#file": ["./dir/file.js"],
            "#colors": ["./commanddata/colors.json"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the right-hand sides of the definitions must be _arrays_, even if they are not in the corresponding entry in package.json

Comment: Does this work with ES6 imports?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but I wanted to toss in this Additional note for vscode, in typescript projects:

I found joy by adding the "paths" notation to my tsconfig.json, thus:

Note that I use a root "#base" notation. Ymmv.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    
    "paths": {
      "#base/*": ["./src/*"]
    }

  }
}
```

vscode, with this entry in my tsconfig.json, doesn't even need the jsonconfig.json file present.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34681608)