# Rollup compatibility with nodejs (subpath) imports

Tags: node.js, rollup

I'm building a javascript library and use Babel/Rollup to transpile and bundle it. My library takes advantage of the NodeJS [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports). My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "mylib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ...
  "imports": {
    "#db/*": "./db/*.js"
  }
  ...
}
```

and in my code, I import internal files as follows:

```
import db from "#db/connect";
```

Unfortunately, when I try to bundle my code, I get an `Unresolved dependencies` error from Rollup. It can't resolve the `#db/connect` path.

For reference, here is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import pkg from "./package.json";

export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.js", // entry point
        output: {
            name: "mylib", // package name
            file: pkg.browser,
            format: "umd",
        },
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            babel({
                exclude: ["node_modules/**"],
            }),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: "src/index.js", // entry point
        output: [
            { file: pkg.main, format: "cjs" },
            { file: pkg.module, format: "es" },
        ],
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: ["node_modules/**"],
            }),
        ],
    },
];
```

How can I tell Rollup to use the [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports) from the `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`; to use subpath imports you will need to use the newer `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, at least version 11.1.0 (current version is 15.1.0). You will probably need to upgrade rollup itself accordingly, too.

Also, the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-patterns) uses kinda-globs (I think `#db/**/*.js` would have been more in line with how such paths should be expressed), but as mentioned in [node-resolve plugin issue #1077](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/1077#issuecomment-1409530730), this particular setup isn't supported by the node-resolve plugin.

Instead, you should specify imports without using any extensions:

```json
  ...
  "imports": {
    "#db/*": "./db/*"
  }
  ...
```

and then import using full file name including extension in the source code (this would also be more compatible with how things should be done directly in a web browser):

```js
import db from '#db/connect.js';
```

If you are using VSCode as your IDE, you should additionally [have a path setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68268894/how-to-get-node-subpath-imports-intellisense-working) in jsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "#db/*": ["./db/*"]
    }
  }
}
```